# How to return all different names in table (Android-Sqlite)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a problem to return all different names from my database Table. The table have following columns:

```
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_BETRAG = "betrag";
public static final String KEY_GRUND = "grund";
public static final String KEY_DATUM = "datum";
public static final String KEY_ICONID = "icon";

    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
public static final int COL_BETRAG = 2;
public static final int COL_GRUND = 3;
public static final int COL_DATUM = 4;
public static final int COL_ICONID = 5;

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_BETRAG,KEY_GRUND, KEY_DATUM, KEY_ICONID};
public static final String[] ALL_DIFFERENTNAMES = new String[] {KEY_NAME};

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE1 = 
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE1 
            + " (" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
            + KEY_BETRAG + " real not null, "
            + KEY_GRUND + " text not null, "
            + KEY_DATUM + " text not null, "
            + KEY_ICONID + " integer not null"
            + ");";
```

With the following method, I want to return all different names, but it did not worked after all

```
    public Cursor getAllDifferentNames1() {

//      String where = "SELECT DISTINCT " + KEY_NAME + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE1;

    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE1, ALL_DIFFERENTNAMES, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }

    return c;
}
```

When I run the application, I get this error message:

```
    01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:302)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:333)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:81)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at fragments.Schuldet_mir.populateListViewFromDB(Schuldet_mir.java:243)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at fragments.Schuldet_mir.onResume(Schuldet_mir.java:99)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1543)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15284)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15284)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:861)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:602)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15284)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2367)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15284)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1867)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1292)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1009)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4236)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4872)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone tell me, what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

the method at the line 99 in class Schuldet_mir:

```
populateListViewFromDB();
......
public void populateListViewFromDB() {                                      //ListView mit Werten aus der db befüllen

        getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor = mainActivity.myDBHandler.getAllDifferentNames1());

        String[] dbSpaltenNamen = new String[] {DataBaseHandler.KEY_NAME,   //die spalteneinträge wie
                                                DataBaseHandler.KEY_BETRAG, //angeordnet in die jeweiligen
                                                DataBaseHandler.KEY_DATUM,  //id's des custom listzeile zuordnen
                                                DataBaseHandler.KEY_ICONID};

        int[] zuListViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.txt_name,                     //hier die id's. name zu name
                                         R.id.txt_betrag,                   //betrag zu betrag...
                                         R.id.datum,
                                         R.id.list_userImage};

        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter 
                = new SimpleCursorAdapter
                            (getActivity(), R.layout.list_zeile, cursor, dbSpaltenNamen, zuListViewIDs);

        verliehenesGeld.setText("" + mFormater.formatDecimal(mainActivity.myDBHandler.getColBetragInTable1()));

        if(mainActivity.myDBHandler.getContactsCountInTable1() > 0) {
            anzahlEinträge.setText("Einträge: " + mainActivity.myDBHandler.getContactsCountInTable1());
        }
        else {
            anzahlEinträge.setText("Keine Einträge");
        }

        listView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

Comment: column '_id' does not exist - `01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at fragments.Schuldet_mir.populateListViewFromDB(Schuldet_mir.java:243)
01-04 16:18:54.878: E/AndroidRuntime(28638):    at fragments.Schuldet_mir.onResume(Schuldet_mir.java:99)`
Please post code for `Schuldet_mir`

Comment: hi ramaral, the line 243 is  
= new SimpleCursorAdapter

Answer (score 0):

All list views require an "_id" column.  The query you are using to generate the cursor does not ask for that column, so the listadapter fails when it tries to process it.  The following should make it work:

```
public static final String[] ALL_DIFFERENTNAMES = new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME};
```

Comment: hi barak, see my answer above.

Comment: Exactly... the SimpleCursorAdapter *requires* an "_id" field to be present.  The cursor you are returning and putting into the adapter does not have that column, so you get the error.  Change your query to include the "_id" field (KEY_ID) and that problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code don't show but I think you are try to acess the _id column on cursor returned from getAllDifferentNames1(). That cursor don´t have that column.

Change

```
public static final String[] ALL_DIFFERENTNAMES = new String[] {KEY_NAME};
```

To:

```
public static final String[] ALL_DIFFERENTNAMES = new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME};
```

**EDIT**

After see method `populateListViewFromDB()` you should change `ALL_DIFFERENTAMES` array to:

```
public static final String[] ALL_DIFFERENTNAMES = 
              new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_BETRAG, KEY_DATUM, KEY_ICONID};
```

You're mixing two different things.
One thing are the columns you want in listview other thing are the rows(data) you want to display.

The rows(data) are in cursor and depend on the query set. Your query seems to be correct.

If you want display only the column `name` on listview, you should change the view used for `listview` to have only one `textview`, the array `dbSpaltenNamen` should have only `DataBaseHandler.KEY_NAME` and use your original `DIFFERENTNAMES`.
For more information see [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: i have tried this already, then i became the message: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'betrag' does not exist

Comment: You cursor must have all columns that you pass to adapter on `dbSpaltenNamen` array. I edited my answer.

Comment: that fix the error i know (look at the array ALL_KEYS- with that i display all rows in the database), but what i am trying to do is, to display a list with the names, which is stored in the database. In the database exists several names, which are the same. for example: Alex, Chris, Tom, Jimmy, Tom, Tom, Chris. the list should display all different names once. (Alex, Chris, Tom, Jimmy)